# manually change the startup scripts in /etc/rc2.d

Tags: startup, openssh

I use ubuntu 14.10 and I want to stop the SSH service from auto startup. Will it be enough to change the start up script to be `/etc/rc2.d/K03ssh` or I should do 
`sudo update-rc.d -f ssh remove` also

Comment: Please [edit] your question to _include the Ubuntu version_.

Comment: i use ubuntu version14.10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no. As explained in `/etc/rc2.d/README`, to disable a service in that runlevel you can rename as you suggest but should also run `update-rc.d script defaults` to reorder the scripts:

> To disable a service in this runlevel, **rename its script in this
>   directory so that the new name begins with a 'K' and a two-digit
>   number, and run 'update-rc.d script defaults' to reorder the scripts
>   according to dependencies.**  A warning about the current runlevels
>   being enabled not matching the LSB header in the init.d script will be
>   printed.  To re-enable the service, rename the script back to its
>   original name beginning with 'S' and run update-rc.d again.

However, it is much simpler and safer to use the tools provided. Instead of removing the `ssh` service, use `update-rc.d` to disable it on runlevel 2:

```
sudo  update-rc.d -f ssh disable 2
```